# WPF MVVM with Tabcontrol worspace

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am a beginner of WPF with MVVM patterns. And I want full demo project for A Josh Smith article here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-FR6L1WGy4ZoZqDDzNg9ATQ&tduid=(5f063ef1c7f1aa57c8b22f23ad49a6dc)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-FR6L1WGy4ZoZqDDzNg9ATQ)().
Where can I get the demo like this article?
Please help me out of this.

Comment: Funny that the link is longer that what you actually wrote. No code, nothing tried, you ask for people to google for you ... good luck.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you want exactly. There are many frameworks for [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel).

[MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/)

[Caiburn.micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/)

Many more but those two are used often.

If you want an example of how to do your own from scratch I have an example of my own that does it from scratch called [Jarloo.Sojurn](https://github.com/kelias/Jarloo.Sojurn).

It really all depends on what you're looking for in terms of what solution you choose.